# Can you suggest some negative point in this post

Tags: discussion, specific-question, down-votes

Can one suggest me some negative points in the following post with several downvote

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/247716/topological-groupoid-structure-on-a-pair-s3-a

Thank you

Comment: I didn't vote down, but it seems that the reader doesn't really get an idea of what kind of answer would be satisfactory.  It might help if you gave some motivation, so we know what direction would be most helpful.  For example, if I set $A$ to be a point, and let the groupoid structure be given by the $SU(2)$ group law, would that earn me a green checkmark?

Comment: @S.Carnahan  I will edit it. For the moment I did an epsilon edit. I ll come bake for more edit. Thanks for your comment

Comment: Some additional reasons for downvotes might be precisely these epsilon edits, as well as that you have posted several questions differing from this one by epsilon.